# Find relationship function between two columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas **dataframe** with 2 columns.

```
|COL_A | COL_B |
|------|-------|
|24.38 | 95.83 |
|36.15 | 96.99 |
|37.90 | 98.13 |
|41.14 | 98.75 |
|63.45 | 98.77 |
|74.95 | 99.04 |
|77.15 | 99.30 |
```

Here in this dataframe, for example, if `COL_A = 24.38` then `COL_B=95.83` and goes like this.

What i want to do is find a relation between two columns for if `COL_A=80` what is the `COL_B=?`.

Comment: I think you're looking for `Linear Regression`

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar can you elaborate? genuinely interested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the question, it seems like `Simple Linear Regression` is what you're looking for.

Simple linear regression is a method that allows us to summarize and study relationships between two continuous (quantitative) variables:

- One variable, denoted x, is regarded as the predictor, explanatory,
  or independent variable.
- The other variable, denoted y, is regarded as the response, outcome,
  or dependent variable.

Basically we try to form an equation `y = wx +b` using existing data 
where

- x is your `COL_A`
- y is your `COL_B`
- w is the vector of weights that we will find using algos like `Grdient Descent`
- b is bias term

Implementation using `scikit-learn`:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

lr = LinearRegression()

lr.fit(df['COL_A'].values.reshape(-1,1), df['COL_B'])

new_x = 80 

new_y = x*lr.coef_[0]+lr.intercept_
print(new_y)
```

Output:

```
99.6
```

There is `predict` method available if you have array for which you have to predict the values. Refer [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html)

Comment: Thanks for this Bhai!

Answer (score 5):

When the data is plotted, it looks almost similar to quadratic.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(df["COL_A"], df["COL_B"])
plt.xlabel("COL_A")
plt.ylabel("COL_B")
plt.show()
```

[image]

We can use polynomial regression of degree 2. Polynomial regression is special case of linear regression.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

X = df["COL_A"].values
y = df["COL_B"].values
X = X.reshape(-1, 1)
poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2)
poly_data = poly.fit_transform(X)
model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(poly_data,y)
coef = model.coef_
intercept = model.intercept_
```

y = intercept +  coef[1] * x + coef[2] * x * x

After plotting model predictions, it can be observed that quadratic is better than straight line. Better model can be obtained by using higher degree in polynomial regression

```
plt.scatter(X,y,color='red')
plt.plot(X,model.predict(poly.fit_transform(X)),color='blue')
plt.legend(['Prediction','Original'])
plt.show()
```

[image]